# Order of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{8}^*$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

$\mathbb{Z}_{8} = \{[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]\}$

I know that ${\rm ord}(a) =\min\{n\ge1:a^{n}= e_{G}\}$ and
${\rm ord}[0] = 1, {\rm ord}[1] ={\rm ord}[3] = {\rm ord}[5] = {\rm ord}[7] = 8, {\rm ord}[2] = {\rm ord}[6] = 4,  {\rm ord}[4] = 8$

I understand how the order of elements are found in $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$ but I'm not sure how this works for $\mathbb{Z}_{8}^*$. How is $[3]^{2} = [5]^{2} = [7]^{2} = [1]?$ (implying that these elements have order $2$)

Comment: $[5]\cdot [5]=[5\cdot5]=[25]=[8\cdot3+1]=[1]$

Comment: Just a comment: $\mathbb{Z}_8 = \{[0],[1],\dots,[7]\}$ (there are 8 classes), and ord$(a) = \min\{n \geq 1 \mid a^n = e_G\}$ (the way you have it written makes it look like ord$(a) = e_G)$. The group operation in $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is usually addition, and the additive identity is [0]. You've got atleast one wrong order for $\mathbb{Z}_8$ (e.g., the order of [4] is 2, not 8).

Comment: @PStheman yeah that's a typo I had it written as 2. That helps reminding me about the group operation of $\mathbb{Z}_{8}^*$ though. That would mean the identity first of all is $[1]$. That clears a little bit of confusion up. Still not sure about those order 2 elements though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align}
[3]\times [3]&=[3\times 3]=[9]=[8+1]=[1],\\
[5]\times [5]&=[5\times 5]=[25]=[3(8)+1]=[1],\\
[7]\times [7]&=[7\times 7]=[49]=[6(8)+1]=[1].
\end{align}$$

Comment: Ahh that makes much more sense, I mainly forgot about the multiplicative thing. So this would mean that $[1]^{1} = [1] = [0 + 1]$ hence ord$[1] = 1$?

Comment: Yes, @DogmanDogman, in $\Bbb Z_8^*$, the order of $[1]$ is one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful which group you are considering. Here $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is an additive group, while $\mathbb{Z}_8^*$ is multiplicative. We have that ${\rm ord}([3])$ is well defined in both groups, but are not at all the same: As $\gcd(3,8)=1$, the order in $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is $8$, *i.e.* $3$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}_8$. In $\mathbb{Z}_8^*$ however, we see that $[3]\times[3] = [9]=[1]$, *i.e.* the order is $2$. A similar calculation holds for $[5]$ and $[7]$.

Comment: Yup, the main thing that got me here was the fact that how different the groups were. It makes much more sense now, thank you